# Как сохранить файл в ту же директорию, из которой выбран файл через jfilechoiser

Tags: java

Выбираю файл с помощью jfilechoser

```
private File file;
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
                ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
                file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                label.setText(file.getName());
            }
```

Затем хочу с помощью, например, FileWriter записать данные в файл, который будет иметь аналогичный путь.
Как это правильно сделать?
Пробовал вот так, не получилось:

```
File Filenew = new File(file + "копия");
```

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите методы File. [Ссылка на docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

```
 File Filenew = new File(file.getAbsoluteFile().getParent() + "\копия");
```